# What does the ellipsis (...) mean in man pages

Tags: linux, manpage

I was reading the `ln` man page and came across the following SYNOPSIS.

```
ln [-Ffhinsv] source_file ... target_dir
```

What does symbol `...` above mean?

Comment: You could have more than one *source-file*, e.g. `ln file1 file2 file3 target-dir/`

Comment: This ellipsis `(...)` is a general symbol used to show that there can be several types realted to previous mentioned type!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That means a repeatable argument (`source_file`).

From `man man`:

```
The following conventions apply to the SYNOPSIS section and can be used
as a guide in other sections.

bold text          type exactly as shown.
italic text        replace with appropriate argument.
[-abc]             any or all arguments within [ ] are optional.
-a|-b              options delimited by | cannot be used together.

argument ...       argument is repeatable.
[expression] ...   entire expression within [ ] is repeatable.
```

According to the man page, calling `ln` like that will create links for all source files in the target directory e.g. `ln file1 file2 file3 target-dir/`.